# Facebook news.reads action not appearing on timeline and newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

News.reads (built-in) actions are successfully published under the Activity Log but not on the timeline and newsfeed. How can I make it appear to my timeline/newsfeed for others to see?

I tried making a custom read action and it was successfully posted on my timeline, newsfeed, and activity log. Will Facebook approve the custom read action?